# Under what circumstances will OVRDBF cause error message CPF5149 to be prompted?

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am currently working on four of CL and RLG programs. The call stack is as follows: A->B->C->D where A is the top caller CL program and D is the bottom callee RPG program. Program A has an OVRDBF statement with SHARE(*YES) option on a file, which is used as output in program D. Now I am facing a problem, which is that whenever D tries to write a record into this file error message CPF5149 is thrown telling me that the I/O operation is not valid. If I comment this OVRDBF statement in program A then D can write the record into the file without any problem. So why exactly does this OVRDBF cause trouble with I/O in a RPG program? How to solve it? Removing it might not be an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SHARE(*YES)` option to [`OVRDBF`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/cl/ovrdbf.htm) keeps the data path open.  If the first program in your call stack that opens the file opens it as read-only then it will stay that way for all other programs.

Generally `SHARE(*YES)` is only used when you want to use the [`OPNQRYF`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/cl/opnqryf.htm) command to filter records before passing them into another program.

---

**UPDATE:**

The open attributes of programs B, C and D (whichever is first to open the file) in your example will control the open status.

If you are using `OPNQRYF` specify the `OPTION(*ALL)` parameter to force it to open the data path with full read/write/update/delete attributes.

---

[IBM i Information Center: Sharing an Open Data Path](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzasc/sc092507374.htm)

Comment: Read only? Do you mean the INHWRT(*YES) option? Currently it uses the default one so I am not sure if the file is opened as read-only.

Comment: @God_of_Thunder No I mean the `F` spec or OPNF/OPNQRYF on the first program in the call stack to open the file.

Comment: There is no OPENQRYF/OPNF in the CL. Any related F spec declarations are set to be update.

Comment: @God_of_Thunder What about delete status?  Each program in the call stack can not request more attributes than the first program that opens the file.  Also check the job log for any diagnostic messages related to the open data path.

Comment: What delete status? I am just using the standard UF A E combination in the F spec. The job log displays a message "Open options ignored". Does this have anything to do with my problem?

Comment: By the way, program B, which is a RPG, also updates the same file but the F-spec uses UF E combination, i.e. no add record option. Do you reckon that this might be the cause of the problem?

Comment: @God_of_Thunder Yes that's the issue.

Comment: So I might have to change the F-spec in program B then? Is there any way to avoid this? I mean is it possible to make all the change in program C and D? Not want to spread the changes across all the programs.

Comment: @God_of_Thunder You can open the file in the CL with `OPNDBF ... OPTION(*ALL)`.  Just be sure to use `CLOF` at the end of your CL to close the ODP.  Or don't use `SHARE(*YES)` if it's not really necessary.

Comment: Just solved the problem today. I have changed the F spec of program B so that it allows records to be added to the file. Thanks for the inspiration.